# Can't get vba function to return correct answer

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning VBA from a book, and the sample function in it is:

```
Function CubeRoot(number)
CubeRoot = number ^ (1 / 3)
End Function
```

If I call that function from a sub procedure, I get the correct result, but when I try to use it directly in Excel, I get a "**FALSE**" result in the cell. I followed the book step-by-step and it does not say to do anything that I haven't done. What am I missing/doing wrong or maybe I need to change some option? I am using **Excel 2016**.

**Edit:**
This is what I write in an excel cell: `=CubeRoot(8)` The result I get is **FALSE**. However, if I click the `fX` button and the function arguments box pops up, the formula result shown there is calculated correctly.

Comment: Edit the question to show how you are calling it from Excel

Comment: Calling from Excel works for me fine.

Comment: To use that function "directly in Excel", enter into a cell: `=CubeRoot(9)` to get the root of 9.

Comment: The function works fine for me in Excel 2010 even when I call it like =CubeRoot("8"). The faulty result you get could be caused by the fact that your function doesn't define any data type. Therefore both `number` and `CubeRoot` are variants. Excel must assign a data type to `(1 / 3)` which can't be a variant. It must then coerce `number` into a data type which can be used in the calculation indicated by `^`and return the result as a variant. Try `CubeRoot = Cdbl(number) ^ (1 / 3)` to give Excel a hint as to what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I write in an excel cell: =CubeRoot(8) The result I get is FALSE

At first try declaring the variable types properly:

```
Function CubeRoot(number As Variant) As Double
 CubeRoot = number ^ (1 / 3)
End Function
```

But I do not believe that this will help because the error result then would be `#VALUE!` but not a boolean `FALSE`.

But the `^` operator can be overloaded. Maybe by some AddIn you are using. So it seems that it was overloaded to be some boolean operator.

Try the following:

```
Function CubeRoot(number As Variant) As Double
 CubeRoot = Application.Power(number, (1 / 3))
End Function
```

If that helps, then my suspicion is true and you should go through your installed AddIns to determine which one is doing the weird overload.

If even the using `Application.Power(number, (1 / 3))` does not help, then the cell containing the formula seems to be formatted using a weird number format. Try formatting it using the `General` number format.

According to your mention: "if I click the fX button and the function arguments box pops up, the formula result shown there is calculated correctly.", I suspect it is the weird number format rather than the first two suspicions. So do selecting the cell containing the formula `=CubeRoot(8)` and set number format `General` to it using **Home** tab and **Number** group.

Finally the problem was that the worksheet functions had been inputted into Excel4 macro sheets instead of worksheets. Probably the Excel4 macro sheets were added using [Sheets.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-add-method-excel) using the type `xlExcel4MacroSheet`. But in Excel4 macro sheets only Excel4 macro code is possible not default formulas as in worksheets. Excel4 macro is ancient type of macro language from Excel 4.0 (1992). Since Excel 5.0 (1993) `VBA` is used for Excel macros.

Comment: I tried all of the above without any luck. The number format was General, and I checked that as well beforehand as I had the same thought. I checked the add-ins and I got none installed.

The other thing I tried is creating the below function just to see if it would right. But I got the same result of FALSE.

    Function RectangleArea(Height As Double, Width As Double) As Double
    RectangleArea = Height * Width
    End Function
@Variatus

Comment: @Alex: So all your VBA UDFs returning double values leads to boolean FALSE if used in Excel sheets? Can you share an example Excel file, uploading it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be the case. Here is a link to the uploaded file. Thanks for helping out.    
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-6Z3FKWU4jE0krXU3CUB6yroONlMZaKG

Comment: @Alex: The sheets `Macro3` ... `Macro1` are Excel4 macro sheets instead of worksheets. Probably they are added using [Sheets.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-add-method-excel) using the type `xlExcel4MacroSheet`. In Excel4 macro sheets only Excel4 macros are possible not formulas as in worksheets. Try your functions in `Sheet1`. This is a worksheet.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. Not sure how I got to Macro sheets, but I won't make this mistake again, and I learned something. The original function as well as the ones you suggested all work now.

Comment: @Alex FWIW, macro sheets are created if you use the shortcut key Ctrl-F11.  (I often do that by accident instead of pressing Alt-F11.)

Answer (score 0):

Declare all variables as double, and also the function return type as double.

By default 8 is treated as integer, so 8*X will result integer even if x is single or double.